# install composer fails in windows 10 The openssl extension is missing

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, composer-php, windows-10

## openssl missing whene install composer

my windows: 10

local server: UwAmp

I've activated openssl in :

C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\php.ini

C:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-5.4.31\php.ini-development & php.ini-production (2 files) by delete - ; -

As well as from UwAmp GUI

### But

### This problem is not solved

> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
>   If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Thank you

Comment: did you recompile php with --with-openssl?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue installing Composer with MAMP for Windows 10. My php.ini file was not in the same directory as `php.exe`. I'm guessing Composer doesn't know to look elsewhere for the ini.

Try making a copy of your php.ini from `C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\php.ini`, pasting it into `C:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-5.4.31`, and then try to run the Composer setup again. Confirm that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is not commented out with a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy php.in from php dir to Apache24/bin works for me. Please make sure you enable the extension in there.

Comment: Worked for me. How should I get to this by myself?))) copy php.ini into all the directories on my PC?!))

Answer (score 0):

Composer has nothing to do with apache, so `C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\php.ini` doesn't matter.

`php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` are sort of examples to get started with. So you should choose one (probably `development`) and rename it to `php.ini` for it to actually work.